# Elementary integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Consider a non-decreasing function $f:(0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^+$ and $T,c>0$ such that for all $t\in(0,T]$. $$\int_{0}^{T}\dfrac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s} ds\le c$$ Then we have for any $t\in(0,T]$ $$\sqrt{f(t)}\le c\log\left(\dfrac{T}{t}\right)^{-1}$$

I saw this inequality in a paper, but I have no idea. In the first sight, I guess it is from Gronwall inequality. Then I have no idea.

Comment: Hint. $\int_t^T\le \int_0^T$

Comment: @Riemann is that $$\sqrt{f(t)}\int_{t}^{T}\dfrac{1}{s} ds\le\int_{t}^{T}\frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s} ds\le c$$

Comment: Yes. Then the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

$f:(0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ a non decreasing function with $T, c > 0$ and $\int_0^T\frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s}ds \leq c$

Now, $f(s) \geq 0 \; \; \forall s \in (0,T] \implies \int_0^t \frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s}ds \geq 0 \; \; \forall t \in (0,T]$

Also, as $f$ is non decreasing, $f(t) \leq f(s) \; \; \forall s \in [t,T]$

So, $$\int_t^T\frac{\sqrt{f(t)}}{s}ds \leq \int_t^T\frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s}ds = \int_0^T\frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s}ds - \int_0^t\frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s}ds $$

$$\implies \sqrt{f(t)} \log \left(\frac{T}{t} \right) = \sqrt{f(t)} \int_t^T\dfrac{1}{s}ds \leq \int_0^T\frac{\sqrt{f(s)}}{s}ds \leq c$$

$$\implies \sqrt{f(t)} \leq c \left( \log \left(\frac{T}{t} \right) \right)^{-1}$$

Hence proved.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes i got it. thank you!